# VIM Convert Text to URL with Search/Replace

Tags: vim

I have a document that contains long filenames, followed by a hyphen, followed by a description of the contents of the file. The files are all PDFs. I am converting this document into a page on our website, so that it has the filename, which should be a link to the file, followed by the description of the file contents.

I'm fairly versed in the basics of VIM, but advanced search/replace is something I'm lacking in. What I'd like to do is convert each filename into a link to that filename. For example:

```
WebAdapt_Prod_Int_10.1_Install.IIS7.2008R2.pdf - Step by step instructions for installing ArcSDE 10.1 for Oracle on the ‘Test’ environment, including configuration notes.
```

Should convert to:

```
<a href="documents/WebAdapt_Prod_Int_10.1_Install.IIS7.2008R2.pdf">WebAdapt_Prod_Int_10.1_Install.IIS7.2008R2.pdf</a> - Step by step instructions for installing ArcSDE 10.1 for Oracle on the ‘Test’ environment, including configuration notes.
```

There are roughly 30 of these documents, so going line-by-line would be time consuming (though by the time I get a response I'll probably already have done it). I'd just like to know how to do this for the next time I'm given a big text file that needs formatting.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
:%s!\v^\S+\.pdf!<a href="&">&</a>!
```

Please note that the above doesn't try to do anything with HTML entities though.  See the [Vim Tips wiki](http://vim.wikia.com/wiki/HTML_entities) for a possible solution if that's a concern.

**Edit:** The way this works:

- `:%` - filter the entire file
- `s!...!...!` - substitute
- `\v` - set "very magic" syntax for regexps
- `^\S+\.pdf` - match one or more non-spaces at the begging of line, followed by `.pdf`
- `<a href="&">&</a>` - replace with the link: `&` is the matched string (that is, the filename).

Comment: Worked like a charm! Any chance you could give a step-by-step on what each command does? I can look it up too, so don't go out of your way. Much appreciated!